# Using DexExtreme modules causing reference errors

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, devextreme

I'm trying to use dx modules:

```
require("devextreme/ui/button");

const em = {
    init: () => {
        $("#button").dxButton({
            text: "Click me",
            onClick: function() {
                alert("The Button was clicked");
            }
        });
    }
};

export default em;
```

But I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dxButton is not a function

I have two separate bundle files also. One called vendor.js:

```
// Vendor
require("expose-loader?$!jquery");
require("lodash");
require("expose-loader?moment!moment");
require("expose-loader?pnp!@pnp/pnpjs");
require("jszip");
```

Another for my app (app.js).

I'm importing dev extreme within that app.js bundle.

Is it possible that because jquery is not in the same bundle that devextreme is failing to recognize it?

Comment: I've never seen devextreme used as an ES6 module. For such question, I think you should ask directly to their support or, eventually, in their github issues section: https://github.com/DevExpress/DevExtreme/issues . Likely, jQuery is not recognized, though I would personally recommend you, unless you're forced to work in this way, to follow the guidelines here: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Common/Introduction_to_DevExtreme/ or find a similar example here: https://github.com/DevExpress/DevExtreme-examples

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add:

```
require("devextreme/integration/jquery");
```